# How to AddRegistry again after React Native app has launched?

Tags: react-native, react-native-code-push

Here is the index.js in my React Native 0.70.x app.

```
/**
 * @format
 */
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';
import codePush from "react-native-code-push";  //code push


AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App); //How to re AddRegistry again after the app has launched?
```

The situation is after the app has launched and gets users consent of privacy policy, the app needs to be re AppRegistry with the code (code push) below:

```
 AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => codePush(App));
```

Is there a way to relaunch the app (re AppRegistry) with codePush as above?